# How to fix broken listview on Android ICS?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

why my listview is broken on android ICS like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/gu9.png/

but not broken on Gingerbread like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/unx.png/

I use phonegap 2.2 and jquerymobile 1.2,

Please help.. :(

Thanks..

EDITED
I use phonegap 2.2 and this AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.clientapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/pathing"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true"
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.clientapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
    android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
    <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
</activity>
    </application>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
</manifest>
```

UPDATE : SOLVED :)

Comment: Posting your xml layout code could help us to identify the faulty.

Comment: Don't use the "fix" tag unless you're talking about FIX protocol.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, you should post it as an answer below.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, i'm newbie here. I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong on my code, this is my code that uncorrect

```
$('#checkedList').append('<li id="'+item.id_wahana+'" class="listClick"><a id="'+item.id_wahana+'" href="#nextWahana"  data-role="button" data-transition="slidefade" data-inline="true"<span class="ui-li-count">'+item.jumlah_antrian+'</span>'+item.nama+'</a></li>');
```

then I add the tag ">" before  . My problem was solved. Thanks